# Sql searches fixed and non-fixed expenses

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
code   |    date      | value    | fixed |  fixedEndDate    |   description
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1    |  2017-28-07  |  50.00   |   1   |      null        |   expense fixed
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2    |  2017-10-08  |  100.00  |   0   |      null        |   expense 2
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3    |  2017-28-08  |  50.00   |   1   |      null        |   fixed expenditure already included
```

I am developing a personal expense system where the client would like the expenses marked as fixed, always be presented in the surveys of the next months. He does not want the fixed expense to be inserted with a definite term. Example, enter this expense for 12 months.

**Column fixed =** Definition that the expense is of the fixed type
**Column fixedEndDate =** Definition that this fixed-type expenditure will be repeated or not. Null means that it will be repeated during the months

The expense posting process is working properly, my problem is how to create expense research per month.

On the screen, the customer selects the month and the system searches for all expenses in that month. I want to develop a way to find all expenses of the month informed + all fixed expenses that did not exist in the informed month.

But the problem is, for example: the fixed expense of code 1 released in July already exists in the month of August, so the search should only return the expenses of code 2 and 3, but my query is returning all 3 records.

**select that I'm using**

```
select *
    from tdespesa
 where datadespesa between '2017-01-08' and '2017-31-08'

 union

 select *
    from tdespesa
 where fixed = 1
    and fixedEndDate is null
   and not exists
         (select *
                  from tdespesa
                 where datadespesa between '2017-01-08' and '2017-31-08');
```

Comment: Is the table you showed the expected result or the content of your table? If it is the result: please add the data in your table. If it is the table: please add the expected result. Also: if it is your table, how did the august row get in there? It does not fit to "He does not want the fixed expense to be inserted with a definite term. Example, enter this expense for 12 months." To do this, you'll have just one row (as you don't know how many you need). Generally, I would not do it this way though, better have table(s) with all actual (past) expenses, and table(s) to manage reoccuring things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the table with the result. But I agree with you, I ended up developing this way, inserting for 12 months or the number of months defined by the customer, and the customer has the option to repeat the expense after the end date.